# Powershell invoke-command with -NoMachineProfile how to get passed args

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

**The Question**

Does anyone know of a method to get the same data as $MyInvocation?  Strong preference is using only built in stuff and not 3rd party add on software to accomplish this.

**The Problem**

When you create a session with -NoMachineProfile $MyInvocation is not populated.  I was hoping there was some other way to get the information just as there is with [System.Environment]::Username is for $env:USERNAME.

I am not able to change the way things are invoked.  Please do not suggest removing -NoMachineProfile as a solution since that is not available as an option.

I do not want to rely on $args because that is post-processing.  Namely quotes, variables and other passed arguments are no longer identical to what they were when they were passed.

**Background**

$MyInvocation.line contains the exact command with 0 parsing provided.

e.g.
SomeScript.ps1

```
write-host ("Invoked line: "+$MyInvocation.line)
```

.\somescript.ps1 foo bar "foo and bar"
yields the following output

```
Invoked line: .\somescript.ps1 foo bar "foo and bar"
```

quotes and all, it means it is capable of being cut and pasted and exactly run the same way with 0 user translation.

**-NoMachineProfile invocation**

```
$SE_ADMIN_CREDENTIALS = Get-Credential
$PS_SESSION_OPTIONS = New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile
$arrayRemoteTarget = "thehostname"
$strScriptToRun = ".\somescript.ps1"
$StrArguments = "arg1,arg2,arg3"

$icmCommand = "Invoke-Command -Credential `$SE_ADMIN_CREDENTIALS -SessionOption `$PS_SESSION_OPTIONS -ComputerName `$arrayRemoteTarget -FilePath `$strScriptToRun -ArgumentList (`$strArguments).Split("","")"

Invoke-Expression $icmCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-sessionoption (new-pssessionoption -nomachineprofile)
```

is another way to do that.

As for passing arguments, i believe

```
$using:variable
```

is what you're looking for

e.g.

```
$listing = "*"
invoke-command -computername $computer -scriptblock {cd /; ls $using:listing}
```

i hope that makes sense.

otherwise you could use "arg[0]" or "args[0]" in the file to run script... should work...

One final note, your quotes in quotes, is likely messing up your script, i'd just replace `split("","")` with `split(',')`